# Subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ generated by two elements (along with unity)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, noncommutative-algebra

Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ denote the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. Let $h_1,h_2\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be two Hermitian matrices. Suppose that $h_1,h_2$ are "relatively irreducible", i.e. they don't have common invariant proper subspaces. What is the dimension of the subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $e,h_1,h_2$, where $e$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix? Especially, what is the condition on $h_1,h_2$ such that $\mathcal{A}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$? [Note: it is easy to see that if $h_1,h_2$ can be simultaneously block diagonalized, then $e,h_1,h_2$ cannot generate $M_n(C)$.]

For example when $n=2$, the Pauli matrices $\sigma^z,\sigma^x$ are enough to generate $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. When $n=3$, it is easy to check that the Gellmann matrices $$\lambda_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},~~\lambda_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
along with identity matrix $e$ could generate $M_3(\mathbb{C})$. I'm curious about what can be said in general.

Comment: The case of the $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrices $\sigma_z$ and $\sigma_x$ generating $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a special case of an important phenomenon. Recall that the complexified *Clifford algebra* on $n$ generators is the unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{l}_n$ generated by $\sigma_1,\dotsc,\sigma_n$ satisfying $\sigma_i \sigma_j + \sigma_j \sigma_i = 2\delta_{ij}1$. If $n$ is even, then $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{l}_n$ is isomorphic to $M_{2^{n/2}}(\mathbb{C})$, and the corresponding irreducible representation is called a *spinor* representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V$ denote the $n$-dimensional vector space where $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ acts on. Then $h_1, h_2$ are "relatively irreducible" is equivalent to that $V$ is an irreducible representation of $\mathcal{A}$. The density theorem of representation theory (Sec.3.2 of the [rep-th book](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0827)) says that if $V$ is an irreducible finite dimensional representation  of a unital  associative algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then the representation map $\rho: \mathcal{A}\to \mathrm{End}V$ is surjective. But $\mathrm{End}V=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is by definition a subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, therefore $\mathcal{A}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

In conclusion, relative irreducibility of $h_1,h_2$ already guarantees $\mathcal{A}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$--we don't need anymore conditions.